Transformer Model Repeating Same Codon During Inference Despite High Training Accuracy
I'm working on a transformer-based model to translate amino acids to codons. During training and validation, my model achieves 95-98% accuracy. However, during inference, I encounter an issue where the output sequence consists of the same codon repeated over and over again, like this:
gcc gcc gcc gcc gcc gcc gcc gcc gcc gcc gcc ...
Here is my inference code:
Define the inference function
def infer(model, path_infer, start_token_id=2, output_level='DNA'): 
    if output_level == 'DNA':
        tokenizer = Tokenizer.from_file(tokenizer_DNAfile)
    else:
        tokenizer = Tokenizer.from_file(tokenizer_RNAfile)
    model.eval()
    infer_data = s.fasta_to_list(path_infer, seq_to_codon=False, separate_aa=True, sos_eos=False)
    fast_tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(tokenizer_file=tokenizer_AAfile)
    src = fast_tokenizer.encode(infer_data[0], padding='max_length', return_tensors="pt", max_length=config['input_length'])
    max_length = torch.count_nonzero(src).item()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        src_embed = model.src_embedding(src)
        memory = model.encoder(src_embed)
        tgt_input = torch.LongTensor([[start_token_id]])
        output_sequence = [start_token_id]
        
        for _ in range(max_length):
            tgt_embed = model.tgt_embedding(tgt_input)
            decoder_output = model.decoder(memory, tgt_embed)
            output_logits = model.fc_out(decoder_output[:, -1, :])
            next_token = output_logits.argmax(dim=-1).item()
            output_sequence.append(next_token)
            tgt_input = torch.cat((tgt_input, torch.LongTensor([[next_token]])), dim=1)
    
    return tokenizer.decode(output_sequence[1:], skip_special_tokens=True)

loading_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, config['model_name'])
model.load_checkpoint(loading_path, model, optimizer)
z = infer(model, path_infer)
print(z)

Details:

Framework: PyTorch

Model: Transformer

Tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizerFast for amino acids, custom tokenizers for DNA/RNA

Training Accuracy: 95-98%

Inference Output: Repetitive sequences (e.g., "gcc gcc gcc...")


Steps I've Taken:

Checked the training and validation stages: The model performs well with high accuracy.

Examined the inference code: Ensure it follows standard transformer inference practices.


Problem:
During inference, the model outputs repetitive codons, which is not expected given the high accuracy during training and validation.
Questions:

What could be causing the model to generate repetitive sequences during inference?

Are there any common pitfalls in transformer inference that might lead to this behavior?

How can I modify my inference function to address this issue?


Additional Information:

Using argmax for next token selection.

The model is loaded correctly and is set to evaluation mode.


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

hey guys, I solved my problem, so I decided to wrote the solution here for those who have the same problem. in my case  the problem was in the masked multi_head attention stage (it did not work properly, so by changing the code it worked). it decreased the number of repetition but not very much,
this paper is really helpful I recommend you reading it, specially for those who use beam-search, top k or other approaches to decrease repetition and increase the diversity
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09751
